# Getting psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Users' in Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-login

I am writing a Flask app using PostgreSQL for my database and am now getting an error.

```
@main.route('/write_post', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def write_post():
form = Posts()
if form.validate_on_submit():
    post = Post(posttitle=form.posttitle.data, postbody=form.postbody.data, author_id=current_user._get_current_object())
    db.session.add(post)
    db.session.commit()
return render_template('post.html', form=form)
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1245, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 581, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'Users'
```

I believe that the issue is psycopg2 is getting an array from the `_get_current_object()` and doesn't know what to do with it. How would I turn adapt the data into something Flask can use?

Comment: Postgres is tellin gyou that you've sent it a `User` object for the column `author_id`, and it doesn't know how to make it into an `author_id`, which is most likely an integer.  You probably want to pass the value of the current user's `id` attribute `post = Post(..., author_id=current_user._get_current_object().id)` might work.

Comment: That is it, and as usual so simple in retrospect.